# WooCommerce Memberships: Grant (Add) a new membership when another expires

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Is there a way to grant (add) a new WooCommerce Membership to a user when their current membership expires?. If the user has gold, when gold expires, grant silver to the user. I'm using SkyVerge WooCommerce Memberships.

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. AutomateWoo. It allows me to create workflow that can create / delete memberships based on a variety of triggers.